# Condition based where clause SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, if-statement, stored-procedures

Can someone suggest how to add a condition in `WHERE` clause of my stored procedure?

```
CREATE Procedure getAllEmployeesByDeptAndFlag
    @Dept int,
    @sal int,
    @Flag int
AS
    if @flag = 1
        select * 
        from employee 
        where Department = @dept and @sal < 10000
    else 
        select * 
        from employee 
        where Department = @dept
```

Is there any way to simplify above procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `or` logical operator to unify both branches of the `if` statement:

```
select * from employee where Department = @dept AND (@flag != 1 OR @sal < 10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define that if you pass in `NULL` for `@sal`, then the salary is not being checked. No need for an extra `@flag` parameter...

```
CREATE Procedure getAllEmployeesByDeptAndFlag
    @Dept int,
    @sal int
AS
    SELECT 
        (list of columns)
    FROM 
        dbo.employee 
    WHERE 
        Department = @dept 
        AND (@sal IS NULL OR salary <= @sal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `OR`:

```
CREATE Procedure getAllEmployeesByDeptAndFlag
@Dept int,
@sal int,
@Flag int
as
    select * 
    from employee 
    where Department = @dept 
    and (@flag <> 1 or @sal < 10000)
```